# UPS integration with Ubuntu 14

Tags: power-management, battery

I'm interesting the opportunity UPS integration with Ubuntu 14.

UPS Mustek PowerMust 800 USB connected to the desktop computer. NUT server is configured  (blazer_usb driver). Both work correctly KNUT client and NUT monitor.

The question is it possible to integrate the UPS in the system that I could use the settings System -> Power in the "Control Panel"?
Or the program BOINC client (distributed computing manager) stops the process when the computer on battery? (this features enabled but system doesn't know when on battery).

On the laptop with integrated battery it works but on the desktop it does`nt.